# IBM Worklight Http Adapters

Tags: http, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM worklight and would like to consume a .NET web service using http adapters. getting the error: "errors": ["Runtime:Runtime: Http request failed: java.net.UnknownHostException:

domain inside the xml typed it in full as [http://localhost/Service/Service1.asmx]

function HelloWorld() {
    var input = {
            method : 'get',
            returnedContentType : 'xml',
            path : "HelloWorld",
            transformation : {
                type : 'xslFile',
                xslFile : 'filtered.xsl'
            }
        };
    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

Answer (score 0):

In adapter's XML

<protocol>http</protocol>

<host>localhost</host>

<port>80</port>

In adapters JS use path:"Service/Service1.asmx"

Also, make sure that your service returns XML and your filtered.xsl contains a valid transformation for returned XML (otherwise just remote transformation property).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing the same mistake I was doing few minutes ago. Your HelloWorld function is incomplete. I suggest if you refer to the way the client is constructing the message as per this question: [IBM Worklight HTTP Adapter SOAP response: XSL transformation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766007/ibm-worklight-http-adapter-soap-response-xsl-transformation-failed)