# Worklight 6.1 and parse MTOM soap response

Tags: soap, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst, mtom

I created a HTTP adapter with a SOAP-based service request.

That work fine but the response is not a 'xml' format.

For example my soap request is the following

```
function getActions(username,password) {

var b64Auth = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(new java.lang.String(username+':'+password).getBytes());
var bAuth = "Basic " + b64Auth;

var request =  
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://ws.tririga.com">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
    <ws:getActionItems/>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>;

WL.Logger.debug("SOAP Request " + request);

var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'plain',
        path : '/tririga/ws/TririgaWS',
        headers: { Authorization: bAuth },
        body: {
             content: request.toString(),
             //contentType: 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8',
             contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
            },
};

return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

}

and after the WL.server.invokeHTTP, the response from the backend is the following

```
{
"errors": [
],
"info": [
],
"isSuccessful": true,
"responseHeaders": {
  "Cache-Control": "no-cache=\"set-cookie, set-cookie2\"",
  "Content-Language": "en-US",
  "Content-Type": "multipart\/related; type=\"application\/xop+xml\"; boundary=\"uuid:db4e0265-c5be-460f-9115-04804f4b61f2\"; start=\"<root.message@cxf.apache.org>\"; start-info=\"application\/soap+xml\"",
  "Date": "Mon, 05 May 2014 14:02:49 GMT",
  "Expires": "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT",
  "Set-Cookie": "JSESSIONID=0000dD8NqkZhfe2PngKJm-H5egF:-1; Path=\/; HttpOnly",
  "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
  "X-Powered-By": "Servlet\/3.0"
},
"responseTime": 173,
"statusCode": 200,
"statusReason": "OK",
"text": "\n--uuid:db4e0265-c5be-460f-9115-04804f4b61f2\nContent-Type: application\/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=\"application\/soap+xml\";\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\nContent-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>\n\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2003\/05\/soap-envelope\"><soap:Body><ns1:getActionItemsResponse xmlns:ns1=\"http:\/\/ws.tririga.com\"><ns1:out><ns2:ActionItem xmlns:ns2=\"http:\/\/dto.ws.tririga.com\"><ns2:taskId>167023<\/ns2:taskId><ns2:workflowId>53990823<\/ns2:workflowId><\/ns2:ActionItem><ns2:ActionItem xmlns:ns2=\"http:\/\/dto.ws.tririga.com\"><ns2:taskId>167023<\/ns2:taskId><ns2:workflowId>53980223<\/ns2:workflowId><\/ns2:ActionItem><ns2:ActionItem xmlns:ns2=\"http:\/\/dto.ws.tririga.com\"><ns2:taskId>167023<\/ns2:taskId><ns2:workflowId>53848722<\/ns2:workflowId><\/ns2:ActionItem><ns2:ActionItem xmlns:ns2=\"http:\/\/dto.ws.tririga.com\"><ns2:taskId>167023<\/ns2:taskId><ns2:workflowId>53847639<\/ns2:workflowId><\/ns2:ActionItem><\/ns1:out><\/ns1:getActionItemsResponse><\/soap:Body><\/soap:Envelope>\n--uuid:db4e0265-c5be-460f-9115-04804f4b61f2--",
"totalTime": 176,
"warnings": [
]
}
```

What is the best way to parse the "text" value ? xslt stylesheet ? javascript ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing `returnedContentType` to XML?

Also see this similar question: [IBM Worklight HTTP Adapter SOAP response: XSL transformation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766007/ibm-worklight-http-adapter-soap-response-xsl-transformation-failed)

[HTTP adapter training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf), slides 20-21

Comment: With returnedContentType to 'xml', i have the following error    : "errors": [
      "Content is not allowed in prolog.",
      "Failed to parse the payload from backend (procedure: HttpRequest)"
Only returnedContentType to 'plain' return no error.

Answer (score 0):

Your response body is basically a string. Adapter will not be able to parse it by itself. However response contains everything you need to parse it manually and then manipulate it within adapter.

Content-Type header contains the indicator of xml start ("start" prop). You can either use it to specify beginning of your xml or just take whatever inside of

```
<soap:Envelope>...</soap:Envelope>
```

Once you got your xml as string - you can parse it using Java code and return back to adapter as parsed JSON, which you'll be able to manipulate or return to client.